# SML - unzip using map

Tags: sml, smlnj

Given a list of tuples,

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

I need to unzip it to look like this

```
 [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

unzip needs to be of type `('a * 'a) list -> 'a list list`.

So far, I have this as my unzip function but my input is incorrect, and I am not sure how to access pass through ('a * 'a).

```
val rec last =
        fn (h::nil) => h
           |(h::list) => last (list)
           | (nil) => raise Empty;

fun unzip [] = []
    | unzip L = [(map hd L), (map last L)];
```

this returns `'a list list -> 'a list list`

Comment: Since your `L` is supposed to be a list of *tuples*, `map hd L`wouldn't make sense since tuples don't have heads. It is also problematic that your `unzip` is nonrecursive. I don't see how `map` is really relevant to `unzip`. A straightforward recursive definition based on pattern matching should work.

Answer (score 4):

You were given a list of tuples

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

And we want to create a function to re-organize them into

```
[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

**We know** the output should look something like:

```
[ [tuple heads], [tuple tails] ]
```

And **we know** *map* gives us an output of `list`, which is the datatype we are looking for.

Thus,

```
fun unzip L = [ (map f1 L), (map f2 L) ]
```

I recognize this as a homework problem, so I will leave it there for you to think about the appropriate function for *map*. Think about how tuple behave and how do you manipulate data inside a tuple. Remember that `f1` should be different from `f2` as the two manipulate different things.

Go Cougs!

Comment: Go Cougs!! Thanks for the insight!

Comment: But a list like `[ (map f L), (map f L) ]` would be a 2-element list whose first and second components are identical, hence couldn't look like `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]`. You would need to map two *different* functions over `L` (if you wanted to use map).

Comment: Yes, the function for the first element should be different from the second. I've edited the code to resemble the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `unzip` using `foldr` in the following way:

```
val unzip = foldr (fn ((x,y), (xs, ys)) = (x::xs, y::ys)) ([], [])
```